# Sping: @EnableHypermediaSupport gives error "No constructor with 0 arguments defined in class ConverterRegisteringWebMvcConfigurer"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am following [Spring Hateoas](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/) documentation where it is [mentioned](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#configuration) :

> To enable the ResourceSupport subtypes be rendered according to the
>   specification of various hypermedia representations types, the support
>   for a particular hypermedia representation format can be activated
>   through @EnableHypermediaSupport.

But the moment I add `@EnableHypermediaSupport` to my configuration class, I get compilation Error in the problem console of my IDE saying

> No constructor with 0 arguments defined in class
>   `org.springframework.hateoas.config.ConverterRegisteringWebMvcConfigurer'

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HypermediaType.HAL)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.api.web"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public WebConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
//other beans
}
```

What might be the issue here?

Comment: Hi @TheCoder. Have you sloved this problem?? i too have this same issue now.

Comment: @raja It's an IDE issue I believe. Latest version of Eclipse STS should resolve the issue. I am using the same codebase on Intellij IDEA and no issues there.